# Helm Chart not deploying correctly

Tags: kubernetes, jira, minikube, kubernetes-helm

I'm starting with **kubernetes** and **helm** using **minikube**.

*I would like to install **Jira** but it seems that I'm doing something wrong because I can't get any IP from the deployed service.*

---

This is what I did :

1) Downloaded the Chart for Jira from [this repository](https://github.com/int128/devops-kompose/tree/master/atlassian-jira-software)

2) Next I pakaged the Chart using

```
helm package .
```

Which created a .tar.gz file.

3) Then I installed the Chart in the following way :

```
helm install xxxx.tar.gz --name my-jira
```

I got the following output :

```
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/PersistentVolumeClaim
NAME                                  AGE
my-jira-atlassian-jira-software  1s

==> v1/Service
my-jira-atlassian-jira-software  1s

==> v1beta2/Deployment
my-jira-atlassian-jira-software  1s

==> v1/Pod(related)

NAME                                                   READY  STATUS    
RESTARTS  AGE
jira-atlassian-jira-software-7d55dc5859-cvwnj  0/1    Init:0/1  0         
1s


NOTES:
Atlassian JIRA Software is starting now.
It takes a few minutes to bootstrap a container.
1. Get the JIRA URL by running:
 export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -n default -l "app=atlassian-jira-software,release=my-jira" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
 echo https://127.0.0.1:80/
 kubectl -n default port-forward $POD_NAME 8443:8443

2. Proceed the Setup Wizard.
   See also: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/running-the-setup-wizard-938846872.html
```

4) Finally I expected that doing :

```
 minikube service my-jira-atlassian-jira-software --url
```

...would give me the ip of the service created by minikube.

Unfortunatly the command returns nothing and the perfomance tab seems to indicate that nothing is happening :-/

---

Any idears of what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: can you execute that kubectl command that is suggested? "kubectl get pods -n default"? I assume this is your local kubernetes? Otherwise the default namesapce isn't a good choice. Are there any pods that would match to a running jira? Also look into the kubernetes events in that namespace - there might be a hint if something is wrong.

Comment: Are your pods running?

Comment: Yep pods are running ! But most events sections are empty and the performance tab is displaying so much green that I don't think much is happening under the hood. Its like I had deployed an empty image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this on in my lab environment. So the steps to fix it are:

0) `kubectl get services --all-namespaces -o wide` you can see that the Jira service is a ClusterIP which is the reason why you can't reach the configuration web page.

> ClusterIP: Exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this
>   value makes the service only reachable from within the cluster. This
>   is the default ServiceType.

1) Apply the yaml file below for running cluster.

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: atlassian-jira-software
    chart: atlassian-jira-software-0.1.0
    heritage: Tiller
    release: my-jira
  name: my-jira-atlassian-jira-software
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: atlassian-jira-software
    release: my-jira
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort`

You can also change ClusterIP to NodePort in the values.yaml in the devops-kompose config files.

2) Run:  `minikube service my-jira-atlassian-jira-software --url` and you will see the address where you can reach your application.

Reason for that is because minikube has been created for testing purposes. The minikube VM is exposed to the host system via a host-only IP address. Another way of solving this issue would be to configure Ingress.

Comment: Thx for your answer ! Unfortunatly after replacing the service.yaml by the one you provided and then executing the command line I only got "Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet..." indefinitely. I finaly got it working by replacing ClusterIP by LoadBalancer using what you told me about the services types.

Comment: Glad I could help, please consider accepting the answer or upvoting if it helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I'll accept it because you gave good advice about k8s and minikube which was helpfull :-) . Now about the resolution of the issue itself, the pod wasn't consuming ressources because the JIRA app is kind of deactivated till you create an account. And about getting the IP I had to change from "ClusterIP" (the default as you explained) to "LoadBalancer".

Comment: I must add that my approach worked on my machine without issue. You made me want to investigate on this - when I get some more results I will share it here if I get something useful.